# Memory question: taking ownership of a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

If I have a subview built in Interface Builder, and I want to give it an actual name, I presume the only way to do this is to create a UIView instance variable in my view controller, and then do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.moveView=[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];    
self.moveView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
```

In so doing, I can now work with this subview using a conventional name, "moveView," rather than addressing it by its index number within the view heirarchy.

Is this is good way of doing something like this (outside of actually using a custom view class)?

Another way that is perhaps easier and does not require that you figure out the index number seems to be just creating a UIView @property IBOutlet and assigning that to the Interface Builder and doing this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView * sensitivity;
```

in @interface.

However, I want to know if the "retain" quality of this @property means that my UIView is essentially using up double the memory, since doesn't the Interface Builder UIView also store this in memory? Or will hooking this up in IB make these one and the same, with just a singe actual UIView instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `IBOutlet`s are a much better idea than referencing subviews by their index.

`retain` doesn't cause a property to copy an object on set—that's what the `copy` attribute is for—it just increments the object's retain count to "claim" it. I highly recommend reading the [iOS Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) if you haven't yet. Also note its [section on nibs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW2).